# Internet Explorer 9 AJAX call fails when logged in with forms authentication

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, forms-authentication

I have traced this error down as far as I can to a line in jquery-1.10.2.js:

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

It throws an exception with the message

> The download of the specified resource has failed.

This error only occurs if I choose to log in with forms authentication (`.ASPXAUTH` cookie is present) regardless of whether authorization is *required* or not.

The error does not occur in Chrome regardless of whether I log in or not.

The Network panel of the IE debugger shows this information about the AJAX request:

```
URL                          Method Result    Type   Received  Taken   Initiator    
/api/FSItem?_=1386871819912         (Aborted)        0 B       < 1 ms  (Pending...)
```

The details of the request shows no headers, no body, no response and no cookies when it fails. When it succeeds, I see information in all these tabs, and it properly reports the request as Method = GET (but no .ASPXAUTH cookie because I can only get it to succeed with I'm not authenticated via Forms Authentication). It's strange that it doesn't even report the Method when the error occurs.

The same error occurs whether I'm in compatibility view or not.
Why is this request aborting and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had code that was (improperly) trying to generate an anti-forgery token only when I was logged in. Normally this would not be relevant on a GET request, but the token was so badly malformed that IE apparently didn't even want to send a request. I had a header whose name was "RequestVerificationToken" and whose value was just a colon. Chrome somehow dealt with this OK, but IE I guess doesn't like sending AJAX requests where a header's value contains *only* a colon. I tried changing the value to something that starts with a colon and something that ends with a colon and those were both OK, so I guess IE just has a problem with a header value that's *only* a colon.